# How can I get process command line from PowerShell Core on Ubuntu?

Tags: powershell, command-line, process, ubuntu-18.04, powershell-core

I'm on a Ubuntu 18.04 server. I know the full command line information can be grabbed by `ps auxww`. For example, by running `ps auxww`, I know the command `/usr/local/bin/my-program -parameter :8888` is running. How can I get the same info from PowerShell? I searched around and all the info is about how to get the command line info on Windows.

Comment: I don't know myself except by using /bin/ls.

Answer (score 0):

**On Ubuntu 18.04 PowerShell**,

did you try `ps -a -F`. It should give the details you are looking for.

if need specific details about the running/all processes try with more options with

`ps --help all` or `ps --help output` commands

```
PS> ps --help output   

Usage:
 ps [options]

Basic options:
 -A, -e               all processes
 -a                   all with tty, except session leaders
  a                   all with tty, including other users
 -d                   all except session leaders
 -N, --deselect       negate selection
  r                   only running processes
  T                   all processes on this terminal
  x                   processes without controlling ttys

Output formats:
 -F                   extra full
 -f                   full-format, including command lines
  f, --forest         ascii art process tree
 -H                   show process hierarchy
 -j                   jobs format
  j                   BSD job control format
 -l                   long format
  l                   BSD long format
 -M, Z                add security data (for SELinux)
 -O <format>          preloaded with default columns
  O <format>          as -O, with BSD personality
 -o, o, --format <format>
                      user-defined format
  s                   signal format
  u                   user-oriented format
  v                   virtual memory format
  X                   register format
 -y                   do not show flags, show rss vs. addr (used with -l)
     --context        display security context (for SELinux)
     --headers        repeat header lines, one per page
     --no-headers     do not print header at all
     --cols, --columns, --width <num>
                      set screen width
     --rows, --lines <num>
                      set screen height
        --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>
                      display help and exit

For more details see ps(1).
```

Comment: This is still just the ps command. I think OP is looking for an answer using Get-Process.